# creating .jar file with a file that calls a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

Sorry if this is a little confusing. I have a java file that uses a compilation command with another jar that I want to make into an executable(not .exe). I followed an online example to make a regular jar but get the NoClassDefFoundError due to the jar that it needs to run not being included. I am not sure what I either need to add to my manifest or the jar creating command to achieve this. 
Thanks

Comment: What are you using to create the jar? The jar you want to include should be identified on the classpath and the command used to create the final jar must be configured to include it in the final archive.

Comment: Are you compiling using a script rather than an IDE...?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: LoginScreen

the LoginScreen file needs a jar that is in the same directory

Comment: I used this site to guide me the above is in my manifest file
http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not written java in a long time but try this,

1. Export(right click and select it from options) the project you're working on
2. Select runnable jar file.
3. Decide what you want to do with libraries
4. Finish.

NB: Try having the class files in the same location as the jar

Comment: Not working in Eclipse at the moment but will try this